# Does this sentence have two objects and complement for one of them?

Tags: complements, objects

> I reflected.  Poverty looks grim to grown people; still more so to children: they have not much idea of industrious, working, respectable poverty; **they think of the word only as connected** with ragged clothes, scanty food, fireless grates, rude manners, and debasing vices: poverty for me was synonymous with degradation.
>   —Jane Eyre

Does the highlighted sentence have the following structure?

`Subject + verb` demanding two arguments (think of) +
object 1 (the word) + object 2 (as) + complement for pronoun 'as' (connected […])

Comment: @bunyaCloven's answer is correct, formally, in traditional grammar. But your analysis makes a lot of sense; I would very much like to know how newer grammars handle constructions of this sort, where the idiom requires a second complement expressed as an adverb phrase. *As X* here cannot be omitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highlighted sentence is not complete till the colon, and the structure is:
Subject+ verb+ object(the word)+adverb(only as connected with... till the colon)

The advocacy of this thought is that the adverb is not complete without a part of it; "only as connected with" can not be split at this example, and the whole thing can answer the sole question asked to the verb with subject: "How do they think of the word?"

And back to your question: No, it just uses one object which is "the word".

Comment: The subject of the sentence is not *the word*, it's *they*; *they* is the noun performing the main action of the sentence, since *they* are the ones doing the *think*ing. *The word* is instead the *object* of the noun's action, since *the word* is what *they* are thinking of.

Comment: it is what i told. but in a question to determine a verb's "duty" in the sentence; i think that having the subject and an object makes more sense if you are perfectly sure about it.

Comment: @KenB Poster specifically identifies *the word* as 'object'.

Answer (score 0):

*Think of* uses just an object. It doesn't use two objects, differently from *give*, or *sent*.

> Alice gave him the rabbit.

> A girl sent him a letter.